# CMOS Transmission Gate Body Bias in 74HC4052

Tags: cmos, nmos, biasing, transmission-gate

[image: 74HC4052 schematic diagram]

Page 2 of the [74HC4052 data sheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4052.pdf) shows a diagram of a transmission gate. I'm curious about the way the body of the NMOS transistors is biased. It looks like when the t-gate is off, the body is connected to ground (V<sub>EE</sub>). When the t-gate is on, the body is connected to the input. Any insight why this is done, and if this is a standard practice with transmission gates?

Comment: It's for **body effect compensation** in (I think) a P-well CMOS process. To get lower and more constant on resistance with signal voltage. Maybe a CMOS IC design maven feels like supplying the math in a proper answer. It dates from the mid-1970s.